# Get the current language in typo3

Tags: typo3

in pi based Extension I have: `$this->pi_getLL('languagekey')` to get my translated variable.My problem is that I want to display my current language , something returns "en"

Answer (score 1):

After a long seach I found the Typo3 returns the current language by `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->lang`

You can find [here](http://www.pi-phi.de/variables.html) many useful variable of Typo3